# Removing lines above specific line in text in python

Tags: python

I have text like this

```
ABC 
DEF
Ref.By
AAA
AAA
```

I want remove all the line before the line Ref.By.

How can I do it in python ?

Comment: So the file should start with `Ref.By`?

Comment: You can parse the file line by line and skip the lines until you find `Ref.By`

Comment: Possible duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705009/how-to-remove-all-lines-above-a-certain-line-in-python). Hope it helps!

Comment: @OmaRPR It does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lines = open('your_file.txt', 'r').readlines()
search = 'Ref.By'
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if search in line:
        break

if i < len(lines) - 1:
    with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(lines[i + 1:]))
```

This is alright provided your file size is well within 2-4 MB. It becomes problematic to store it in memory beyond that point.

Comment: How to remove the Ref.By as well ?

Comment: @Jitesh I changed `lines[i : ]` to `lines[i + 1]`. It'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
text_str = """ABC
DEF
Ref.By
AAA
AAA"""

text_lines = text_str.split("\n")

idx = text_lines.index("Ref.By") + 1

result_text = "\n".join(text_lines[idx:])

print(result_text)
```